# XPath to select a table row that has a cell containing specified text

Tags: html, xpath

How do I select a table row that has a cell containing specified text with XPath?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and solution. Do note that the answer of stefan.natchev doesn't select all rows with the wanted property. :)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**Use**:

```
ExpressionSelectingTable/tr[td//text()[contains(., 'targetString')]]
```

**This means**:

Select every `tr` that is a child of any table selected by the expression `ExpressionSelectingTable` and that (the `tr`) has at least one `td` child that has at least one text-node descendent that contains the string `'targetString'`

Comment: I think you might want `ExpressionSelectingTable//tr[...]`, since the rows could be children of `thead`, `tbody`, and/or `tfoot`.

Comment: @Phrogz: Yes, this is a good observation, thanks. My html is a little bit rusty... I did this on purpose, because there may be a table within table and I didn't want to select the outer table..

Comment: Maybe it is worth moving the notice about `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` to the answer itself because this is where I fell short when writing an `ExpressionSelectingTable`. I'm guessing it is common.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, Hi. Sorry for my stupid question. I tried to use you suggested code in my code like this :  
xpath('//table[@class="table table--collapsible"]/tbody[@class="tbody"]/'
                                           'tr[td//text()[contains(., "1 minute driving ")]]')

when I tried to print output it shows me the output like this: 
<Element tr at 0x7f2890fd6a48>

I want to see the returned values of this row. how can I access to the content of this return row in python?

Answer (score 13):

To select rows with cells containing some text you would use this XPath expression:

`//tr/td[normalize-space(text())="Banana"]/..`

This selects any `td` that contains text "Banana" and then selects the parent with `/..`

Comment: This does not answer the question -- what must be selected is rows that have cells that contain Banana. Your answer doesnt select a tr`with a single `td` that has the value of 'Apples and a Banana'

Comment: Also, it isn't good style to reach a certain node and then to climb back -- in most cases an equivalent expression exists that uses only forward axes.

Comment: Although the question asked for a "contains" query, I'm glad to see this tip about using "normalize_space" when you want the text to match exactly except for whitespace.