# XPath with optional element in hierarchy

Tags: html, xpath

As in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608097/xpath-to-select-a-table-row-that-has-a-cell-containing-specified-text/4608452#4608452) imagine that you need to select a particular table and then all the rows of it. Due to the permissiveness of HTML, all three of the following are legal markup:

```
<table id="foo"><tr>...</tr></table>
<table id="foo"><tbody><tr>...</tr></tbody></table>
<table id="foo"><tr>...</tr><tbody><tr>...</tr></tbody></table>
```

You are worried about tables nested in tables, and so don't want to use an XPath like
`table[@id="foo"]//tr`.

If you could specify your desired XPath as a regex, it might look something like:
`table[@id="foo"](/tbody)?/tr`

In general, how can you specify an XPath expression that allows an optional element in the  hierarchy of a selector?

*To be clear, I'm not trying to solve a real-world problem or select a specific element of a specific document. I'm asking for techniques to solve a class of problems.*

Comment: Oh, and for the sake of simplicity and generality I'm ignoring the `thead` and `tfoot` elements legal in HTML.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't see why you can't use this:

```
//table[@id='foo']/tr|//table[@id='foo']/tbody/tr
```

If you want one expression without node set union:

```
//tr[(.|parent::tbody)[1]/parent::table[@id='foo']]
```

Comment: Your first answer is what Dimitre was suggesting. I've switched acceptance for your second expression, however, as this is more DRY.

Comment: @Phrogz: THis expression contains backward axesand is less efficient than an expression that only contains forward axes. As for "DRY"-ness, you may also want to consider the understandability of an expression, which is certainly interconnected with its maintainablity. :)

Comment: @Dimitre Thank you for your comment on efficiency. You are right that the simple alternation (your answer and the first expression in this answer) is easier to understand, even if it is slightly more prone to editing mistakes and harder to maintain.

Comment: @Phrogz: Easier to understand means easier to maintain!

Comment: @Phrogz: I also think that the union expression is more simple and readable. But, unless you have a very cleaver XPath engine, I think that the union expression (with two `descendant` axis) is going to be less efficient

Answer (score 12):

In XPath 2.0, the optional step can be expressed as `(tbody|.)`.

```
//table[@id="foo"]/(tbody|.)/tr
```

[<kbd>XPathTester.com demo</kbd>](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/110b1a6519c9a140ad798771fcfa3da2)

The pipe (`|`) denotes [union](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#combining_seq) (of two node-sets), the [dot](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-context-item-expression) (`.`) denotes identity step (returning just what the previous step did).

This can be expanded to include more optional elements at once:

```
//table[@id="foo"]/(thead|tbody|tfoot|.)/tr
```

Comment: I am not sure why this does not work in XPath 1.0, though. Seems like it should, because `(tbody|.)` looks like a valid `FilterExpr` token (`PrimaryExpr` → `'(' Expr ')'` → `OrExpr` → `AndExpr` → `EqualityExpr` → `RelationalExpr` → `AdditiveExpr` → `MultiplicativeExpr` → `UnaryExpr` → `UnionExpr`).

Answer (score 8):

**Use**:

```
   //table[@id="foo"]/*[self::tbody or self::thead or self::tfoot]/tr
   |
   //table[@id="foo"]/tr
```

Select any `tr` element that is a child of any `table` that has an `id` attribute "foo" or any `tr` element that is a child of a `tbody` that is a child any `table`.

Comment: I appreciate your expertise in this area, but is this really the best that can be done? If the first and last parts of the xpath are just "table" and "tr" this isn't too bad, but with something like `div[@id="contents]//table[@class="comments"](/tbody)?/tr/[td//text()[contains(., 'targetString')]]` it becomes very non- [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) to duplicate the expression around the one variation.

Comment: @Phrogz: No, it is almost as simple as my initial expression -- see the edit. It can be much more elegant with XPath 2.0 and even much more elegant with an XML document with a known XML schema (which is the case with XHTML).

Comment: What is the more elegant XPath 2.0 version ?  The best I could figure out was a step alternating "." and the optional part. With Saxon on TEI, this worked for me: /TEI.2/text/(.|group/text)/body/div1

Comment: @StevenD.Majewski, `//table[@id="foo"]/(tr|(tbody|thead|tfoot)/tr)`