# Parse table using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I would like to parse a table using Nokogiri. I'm doing it this way

```
def parse_table_nokogiri(html)

    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

    doc.search('table > tr').each do |row|
        row.search('td/font/text()').each do |col|
            p col.to_s
        end
    end

end
```

Some of the table that I have have rows like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
     Some text
  </td>
</tr>
```

...and some have this.

```
<tr>
  <td>
     <font> Some text </font>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My XPath expression works for the second scenario but not the first. Is there an XPath expression that I could use that would give me the text from the innermost node of the cell so that I can handle both scenarios?

---

I've incorporated the changes into my snippet

```
def parse_table_nokogiri(html)

    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
    table = doc.xpath('//table').max_by {|table| table.xpath('.//tr').length}

    rows = table.search('tr')[1..-1]
    rows.each do |row|

        cells = row.search('td//text()').collect {|text| CGI.unescapeHTML(text.to_s.strip)}
        cells.each do |col|

            puts col
            puts "_____________"

        end

    end

end
```

Comment: What if there are multiple innermost cells? Do you just want the text content of the entire cell?

Comment: Actually, yes. That would be perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use**:

```
td//text()[normalize-space()]
```

This selects all non-white-space-only text node descendents of any `td` child of the current node (the `tr` already selected in your code).

Or if you want to select all text-node descendents, regardles whether they are white-space-only or not:

```
td//text()
```

**UPDATE**:

The OP has signaled in a comment that he is getting an unwanted `td` with content just a `'&#160;'` (aka non-breaking space).

**To exclude also `td`s whose content is composed only of (one or more) nbsp characters, use:**

```
td//text()[translate(normalize-space(), '&#160;', '')]
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, your solution worked for me. Could you tell me how I can unescape the HTML strings? Is the best way of doing this is through the `cgi` module?

Comment: @Mridang-Agarwalla: In case the text contains escaped markup (very bad practice!) I would recommend that this text be re-parsed and then the markup nodes can be saved/output as markup again. In XSLT one could use the DOE (disable-output-escaping) attribute but this practice should be avoided if another solution is possible.

Comment: It seems that I might have caused some confusion. What I'd like to do is have strings such as #&160, &nbsp, etc etc to be converted into their normal form. The HTML markup is perfectly fine. Thank you.

Comment: Hi again Dimitre, I'm having a little trouble with the XPath you gave earlier. I'm trying to parse this page http://www.jthomas-india.com/main/catsrch.asp?sale=4&loc=Calcutta&product=1&move=next&page=0. I'm getting an extra column after each column with the text - &#160;. Could you help me out please?

Comment: @Mridang-Agarwalla: `normalize-space()` only eliminates whitespace-only text strings, &#160; isn't a white-space character (in XPath terminology). Therefore, use: `td//text()[normalize-space(translate(., '&#160;', ''))]`

Comment: Dimitre, I'm getting the following error when i try to use the Xpath expression in my code. Here's the error that I'm getting `unexpected 'translate(' after 'normalize-space(' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)`. ANy ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: @Mridang-Agarwalla: `td//text()[translate(normalize-space(), '&#160;', '')]` is a correct XPath expression and I have verified that it selects exactly the wanted text nodes. Most probably you hava a copy and paste error. Do note that `translate()` comes *before* and not *after* `normalize-space()` -- did you modify the XPath expression from my answer?

Comment: I copied and pasted the XPath expression that you mentioned. Here's what my line looks like. I'm still getting that same error. `cells = row.search('td//text()[translate(normalize-space(), ''&#160;'', '''')]').collect {|text| text.content.strip}`

Comment: @Mridang-Agarwalla: I don't know what the `row.search()` method does, but it seems that you have too-many nested apostrophies in this expression.

Comment: My bad. I copy-pasted the wrong bit here. I even changed my code to make it a bit simpler. It is `cells = row.xpath("td//text()[translate(normalize-space(), '&#160;', '')]")`. This is the methid I'm using http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-xpath but I still get extra columns for each of the cells for the nbsp.

Comment: @@Mridang-Agarwalla: This can happen only if the `&nbsp;` is not replaced with its corresponding character (`&#160;``) by the parser you are using -- but in this case the parser must issue an error. Are you sure it is `&nbsp;` (maybe the ending semicolumn is missing, or there are other characters)?

Comment: Yup, it's a non-breaking space. The original HTMl has `&nbsp;` and when running the code I get `&#160;`. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: @Mridang-Agarwalla: Can you produce the minimal XML document on which my XPath expression selects a text node that contains such `&#160;`?

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I got around this using a slightly kludgy method — before loading the document into Nokogiri, I substituted all the non-breaking spaces with regular spaces using `html.gsub("&nbsp;", " ")`. Like I said, it's kind of kludgy and I don't know the repercussion, but it gets the job done. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
doc.search('//td').each do |cell|
  puts cell.content
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple (but not DRY) way of using alternation:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML <<ENDHTML
<body><table><thead><tr><td>NOT THIS</td></tr></thead><tr>
  <td>foo</td>
  <td><font>bar</font></td>
</tr></table></body>
ENDHTML

p doc.xpath( '//table/tr/td/text()|//table/tr/td/font/text()' )
#=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80428814 "foo">,
#=>  #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x804286fc "bar">]
```

See [XPath with optional element in hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611474/xpath-with-optional-element-in-hierarchy) for a more DRY answer.

In this case, however, you can simply do:

```
p doc.xpath( '//table/tr/td//text()' )
#=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80428814 "foo">,
#=>  #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x804286fc "bar">]
```

Note that your table structure (and mine above) which does not have an explicit `tbody` element is invalid for XHTML. Given your explicit `table > tr` above, however, I assume that you have a reason for this.