# XPath Optional Node

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I am working with a document that has data in various depths depending on the characteristics of the parent node. Both of these expressions return data:

```
//TITLE/SUBTITLE//PART[SECTION/SECTNO[text() = '§ 400.1']]
//TITLE/SUBTITLE//PART[SUBPART/SECTION/SECTNO[text() = '§ 415.1']]
```

Obviously the only difference is that on has a "SUBPART" and the other doesn't. Is it possible to make "SUBPART" optional?

Comment: The section numbers are irrelevant they are the value I will be searching on. The only relevant optional value is SUBPART.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath with optional element in hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611474/xpath-with-optional-element-in-hierarchy)

Answer (score 4):

**In XPath 2.0 you can use union (`|`) in the path step like so :**

```
//TITLE/SUBTITLE//PART[(SUBPART|self::*)/SECTION/SECTNO[text() = '§ 415.1']]
```

**The following is a demo using a different XML sample :**

XML :

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <optional>
            <child>a</child>
        </optional>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>b</child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

XPath :

```
/root/parent[(optional|self::*)/child]
```

Output :

```
<parent>
    <optional>
        <child>a</child>
    </optional>
</parent>
<parent>
    <child>b</child>
</parent>
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/2G8rsIe41)</kbd>**