# What is the shortest Xpath I can write to select either an element or the child of a different element?

Tags: html, xpath

I want to write an Xpath (1.0) where, with a common base element, it selects elements with different tag types and levels of depth. For example, I can use the following Xpath at the Google site:

`//*[@id='main']/span | //*[@id='main']/div/script`

...with the following HTML:

```
<div id="main" class="content" data-jiis="cc">
    <span id="body" class="ctr-p">
    <div id="footer" class="ctr-p">
    <div id="footc" data-jiis="uc" data-jibp="h">
        <script>
        <div id="xfoot">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Though I'd much prefer it as something along the lines of:

`//*[@id='main'](/span | /div/script)`

...which is an illegal expression. I tried some `self` stuff, but I can't figure out how to get it to grab the `script`, rather than the `div`:

`//*[@id='main']/*[self::span | self::div/script]`

I understand that `self::div/script` means to select a `div` with a `script` child, but I can't figure out the axis (if one exists) to select the `script` in this instance. How might I accomplish this? Or must I use the first Xpath I described?

Comment: In what context/language do you use XPath expressions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4616333/1030675

Comment: @choroba I'm using them in Java with Selenium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have optional axes in the middle of an XPath expression. You can turn the query inside out, though:

```
//*[self::span or self::script[parent::div]][ancestor::div[@id="main"]]
```

Comment: In the `[self::span or self::script[parent::div]]` segment, what's the difference between using `or` or `|`?

Comment: inside `[` you have a logical expression and or is just the logical or. `|` in contrast is not at logic level but at nodeset level and merges the two nodesets like in your original question. I think there is no "intersection" which would be the analogon for logical `and`

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2.0 you can write

```
//*[@id='main']/(span | div/script)
```

But that's not legal in 1.0

If you're asking questions like this you really need to specify which XPath version you are talking about.

Comment: I guessed that was what v1 meant.