# What XPath that selects a element in <tr> which has a particular 'X' in one of its <td> tags

Tags: xpath

```
<tr id="" class="">
   <td class="level 1" style="">
     <td class="Level 1: Sub level 1" style="">
        <a title="Tricky">
          <img src="edit.png">
        </a>
        <a title="Tricky-2">
          <img src="reports.png">
        </a>
        <span class="eoc_indicator"></span>
     </td>

     <td class="level 1: Sub level 2" style="">
        <a target="" href="">Hello world</a>
     </td>
</tr>
```

I need to select the element "img src='edit.png'" element which is in the td class:'level 1: sub level 1' which is in a `td` tag class = 'level 1' that contains a `td` element with a text 'Hello World'

the xpath I thought of was something like this

```
tr[**/td/a[contains(@text,'Hello World')]]/td/a/img[contains(@src,'edit.png')]
```

but I am unable to locate, what am I doing wrong???

Comment: Related (and contains a good answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608097/xpath-to-select-a-table-row-that-has-a-cell-containing-specified-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `@text`, it's `text()`: `@text` looks for the attribute `text`. `text()` selects all text node children of the context node.

Use the XPath below (I believe it is simpler):

```
tr[contains(*/td/a/text(),'Hello World')]/td/td/a/img[contains(@src,'edit.png')]
```

---

On a side note, I don't know everything about XPath, but it seems like `**` (**two** asterisks) is not valid. It gives a syntax error in my tool and I can't find it in the any of the XPath specs[[1]](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)[[2]](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/).

This way, to make your original expression work, just fixing the `@text`->`text()`, removing the double asterisks `**`->`*`, and adding the necessary `/td/` at the end should suffice:

```
tr[*/td/a[contains(text(),'Hello World')]]/td/td/a/img[contains(@src,'edit.png')]
   ^               ^   ^^                 ^^^
```

Or, if you want to match the `'Hello World'` at any level:

```
tr[//td/a[contains(text(),'Hello World')]]/td/td/a/img[contains(@src,'edit.png')]
   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the XPath expression you are looking for

```
tr[//td/a[contains(text(),'Hello world')]]/td/td/a/img[contains(@src,'edit.png')]
```

It was tested with [online XPath tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/). I had add `</td>` right before `/<tr>`, because the sample you've provided wasn't well-formed xml.

Comment: I don't see the check for 'Hello World', and the `//` starts at the top of the tree.  How about `tr[.//a[contains(.,'Hello World')]/td/a/img[contains(@src,'edit.png')]` ... and the `contains()` isn't needed if the entire string is checked: `tr[.//a='Hello World']/td/a/img[@src='edit.png']`

Comment: I see you added the check for 'Hello World', but the first argument should be `.` not `text()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work and should be easy to understand:

```
/tr/td[td/a='Hello world']/td/a/img[@src='edit.png']
```

or you can start the xpath with `//tr` if `tr` isn't your root element.

---

The easiest way for me to construct an xpath like this is to get the direct path and then narrow the scope by adding the predicates.

So I'd start with:

```
/tr/td/td/a/img
```

add the predicate for "Hello world":

```
/tr/td[td/a='Hello world']/td/a/img
```

and then add the predicate for "edit.png":

```
/tr/td[td/a='Hello world']/td/a/img[@src='edit.png']
```